# Android EditText: need to combine multiline and long string

Tags: android, android-edittext, editor

I'm trying to implement something like a text editor.
I want to have a possibility to edit a long string without word-wrapping.
The edited string should be scrolled horizontally.
New line should be entered only when I press Enter.
So, my editor should be able to edit as long string as user desires (with horizontal scrolling) and be simultaneously multi-lined.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editor"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:lineSpacingExtra = "3sp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:typeface="monospace"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
android:gravity="left|top"
android:text="Code editor"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
```

In this case long strings are word-wrapped.

And

```
android:inputType="text"
```

gives me a possibility to edit long strings in one line... but how to enter a new line?
Pressing [Enter] doesn't enter a new string, just the next focusable element is selected.
I tried all combinations that could imagine, but nothing worked properly.

Either the text is multi-lined with word-wrapping or it's presented in one wide line.
I wondering if it's possible at all, to get such desired behaviour.

Now I'm thinking about subclassing EditText and manually handling Enter pressing.
But I don't like this approach.

How to get horizontally scrollable EditText with 'multiline' feature?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want it to be horizontally scrollable?  That doesn't make sense in the context of a multiline editbox, that's why `textMultiLine` works the way it does.

Comment: My editor is intended to to be a 'code editor'. On the left of it there will be a margin bar with line numbers. When a string is automatically word-wrapped, an additional row number appears on the margin bar (although the string is considered by interpretator as one string) - that will be a confusing discrepancy.
Sure, I may try to eliminate that discrepancy, but my current goal is  to discover how to get that desired editbox behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the MUTILINE input type and the ability to scroll horizontally:

```
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

or in xml :

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    .../>
```

Comment: The miracle did not happen :)
I had a litlle hope that that magic combination of "text|textMultiLine" could help me.
Alas, automatic word-wrapping still exists.

Comment: Now I investigate how 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
affects on the bevaviour of my editor.
It seems that 
    android:layout_width="2000dp"
slightly closes me to win )

Comment: I tested this on samsumg S4 and I don't have word-wrapping. The only way to go to next line is to press the enter key.

Comment: all right :)

your approach works fine on the real devices.
The problem exists only on emulators (have tested on 3-rd party BlueStacks... now trying to check this on Genymotion).
Many thanks you was not lazy test this on your device.